# Android getContext based on current thread? (ThreadLocal?)

Tags: android, android-context

I'm a bit tired of always passing around a `context` between my various classes for simple things such as Toast or Alert dialogs, getting application Name and Version, or even just accessing my SQLite database, etc. All of these require the instance of `Context` to function.

I have a super class for all of my `Activity`'s. In such cases, `context == this`. I have many helper methods I use to unclutter my main activity code. .

However, for other classes such as Helpers, `Service`s, `BroadcastReceiver`s, etc. `this != context` so I'm always having to pass an extra `context` variable.

In many cases, even these other classes operate on the `main` thread. Is there a way I can get the correct `Context` for the currently running thread? I'm thinking of creating my own `ThreadLocal` system, perhaps in my `Application` subclass, but I am not sure if this is a stable approach.

What would you recommend to get the context for the current thread?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way I can get the correct Context for the currently running thread?

No, because there is no such concept. If you have 14 activities, 2 services, and a custom `Application` subclass, all in memory at one time, they are all "the correct Context" for the main application thread, as their most of their methods will be called on that thread.

> I'm thinking of creating my own ThreadLocal system, perhaps in my Application subclass, but I am not sure if this is a stable approach.

It would not be. Moreover, it would pretty much ensure that you have [the wrong context most of the time](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

> getting application Name and Version

Use `BuildConfig`

> Alert dialogs

Use the activity that is showing them, as there is no other correct answer.

Comment: This is a good answer. I have a followup question. If *"14 activities, 2 services, and a custom `Application` subclass ... are all 'the correct Context'"*, would it be possible to get the `Application` subclass specifically based on the current thread. (narrowing the list to one possible `Context`) While this is not desirable for Alerts or Toast, it would be a good way to open the `SQLiteDatabase` connection, among other things.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: "would it be possible to get the Application subclass specifically based on the current thread" -- since there is only one `Application` instance per process, it is not tied to any thread. I don't like making a `static` field with that `Application` instance, as I feel it leads to `Context` misuse, but there is no technical reason why you could not just do that. For example, it will not introduce a memory leak, as `Application` already is a global-scope singleton. It is effectively pre-leaked, and you cannot leak it further by having more references to it.

Answer (score 1):

> However, for other classes such as `Helpers`, `Services`, `BroadcastReceivers`, etc. `this != context`.

This is partially true:

- `Helper`'s `this != context` (*if doesn't extend [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)*)
- [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)'s `this == context`, no need to pass an extra context variable
- [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)'s `this != context`, but it's passed into [`onReceive(Context, Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))

> In many cases, even these other classes operate on the main thread.

Classes do not operate on any thread. Class instances reside on the heap memory of dedicated process while running threads call methods of (operate on) the instances. Hence, a thread during its execution may call methods of different objects among which there might be none or up to a few `Context` instances (e.g. `Application`, `Activity`, `Service` etc).

> Is there a way I can get the correct `Context` for the currently running thread?

From the point of view of API, there is no such a notion in `Android` framework as *context of thread*. From the point of view of implementation, it'd be error prone and, taking into account above said, meaningless in the case where a running thread calls methods of the object that doesn't extent `Context` (e.g. `Helper`).

Comment: *"Classes do not operate on any thread."* I understand this. What I meant to say, is that many of the methods in the auxiliary classes are only called via the `main` thread. Additionally I will have static methods which are only called via the `main` thread. If called from another thread then I will have to solve that on my own.

Comment: @George Bailey _"I understand this."_ I believe you do, just tried to be specific in the answer. _"If called from another thread then I will have to solve that on my own"_ In addition to CommonsWare: by initializing a static class member in `onCreate()` of `Application`'s subclass whose instance is the 1st component created upon the process start, you can statically access it from another thread. _"...it would be a good way to open the SQLiteDatabase connection"_ You can pass any `Context`'s subclass and later use `contextsubclass.getApplicationContext()` to get the application-level context.